# finitely generated over invariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, invariant-theory

I was wondering if there are some conditions we can add to the following statement to make it true

"The ring $R$ is finitely generated as a module over $R^G$, where $G$ is a finite group and $R^G$ the ring of invariants".

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the ring $R$ is Noetherian and the order of $G$ is invertible in $R$, the statement it's true (check "S. Montgomery. Fixed rings of finite automorphisme groups of associative rings. L.N.M.
818.", Corollary 5.9.).

Edit: Actually, you can obtain the same result if $R$ is semisimple Arinian (Theorem 2.19, same reference).