# Is $R$ a finitely generated algebra over $R^G$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, $G$ a finite group acting on $R$, $R^G$ its invariant subring. Is $R$ a finitely generated algebra over $R^G$? Is $R^G$ a noetherian ring?

Comment: The answer is yes if $|G|$ is invertible in $R$, and no in general. (See [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book59/files/63kollar.pdf), Example 13 and Proposition 23.)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467104/finitely-generated-over-invariants